What word or phrase describes a person who claims that everyone flirts with them or wants to sleep with them?
I am looking for a word to describe a person who claims that everyone flirts with them or makes a pass at them. For example:

She was overheard (NEED WORD or PHRASE) by multiple employees who complained to HR. They are fed up with her constant (NEED WORD) that every male in the office wants to get into her pants.


Do you mean someone who tends to invite such flirting (e.g., coquette) or someone who claims everyone is out to get them in a less inviting way (sort of like being paranoid)?

There are lots of terms for people who believe themselves to be irresistibly sexually attractive, certainly. Not sure specifically about flirting.

Please edit to provide a sample sentence showing how the word might fit into it.

Someone might be "full of themselves" if they have an exaggerated sense of how worthy they are.

Example suggests a verb is needed.

You don't make clear whether she is complaining of harassment or bragging.  Even if people are complaining about her to HR, it could still be either: they could think her complaints are unfounded and putting coworkers in jeopardy.  Which is it?

For a female, "a vamp" would come pretty close.

With no more details, the best you're going to get is 'deluded/delusional'. With more context 'misguided' could work, but where is the context?

Perhaps

... They are fed up with her obsession that every male in the
office wants to get into her pants.

Given that an obsession is persistent/ongoing, I wouldn't use constant with it.
obsession (n.)

A persistent disturbing preoccupation with an often unreasonable idea
or feeling.
M-W


An idea, image, or influence which continually fills or troubles the
mind; a compulsive interest or preoccupation; the fact or state of
being troubled or preoccupied in this way.
[OED online]

Obsession also leaves open the degree of truthfulness of her claim: it could be a complete fabrication (e.g., for retaliation or a desire for affection/attention) or an exaggeration/generalization of the improper behavior of some number of the men.

The last need word:
Desperation

This is a [predictable] 'comment' rather than the close fit an 'answer' requires, COG P. It hardly works in the example sentence OP provides.

Can you provide a source or dictionary definition of how this answers the question?  Please see the helpful [help] and take a [tour] of EL&U.
